# Пару вопросов по EasyMapping

Tags: ios, json

Мне надо «замапить» ключ "photos", я использую *CoreData*.

Как правильно «замапить» массив, если это возможно, конечно?

В базе тип ключа я указал как `NSData`.

```
{
     id: 262,
     title: 'Fort Hamilton',
     photos : [
                   'http://url//locations/47/photo/ab/db/eb/4d/2122/photo_2122.jpg',
                   'http://url//locations/47/photo/5a/1e/3a/5a/2123/photo_2123.jpg'
               ]
}
```

Могу ли я «замапить» вот такой *JSON*:

```
{
street: 'bla',
city: 'bla bla',
coordinates:{
           lat : 12345,
           lon: 12345
       }
}
```

вот так?

```
+(EKManagedObjectMapping *)addressMapping {
    return [EKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Address class]) withBlock:^(EKManagedObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapPropertiesFromArray:@[@"street", @"city"]];
// не хочу создавать новый NSManagedObject для двух переменных
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"coordinates.lat" toProperty:@"latitude"];
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"coordinates.lon" toProperty:@"longitude"];
    }];
}
```

Надо регистрировать *маппинги* или это как-то автоматически происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) можно так:

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"photos" toProperty:@"photos" withValueBlock:^id(NSString *key, id value, NSManagedObjectContext *context) {
            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:value]];
            return data;
        }];
```

2) Да

3) В случае с примером из репозитория - да, в другом случае можно маппинг объекта вложить сразу в метод `objectMapping`